# allure reports without running a build

Tags: report, testng, allure

I am running automation tests in my local workspace. The test project hasn't been added to a build integration process yet. So I'd like to generate allure reports without running a build.

The necessary dependencies were added to Ivy.xml according to instructions (see https://github.com/allure-framework/allure-core/wiki/TestNG -> Ant), but I don't have a build.xml file, so I have no idea of what the next step is about.

Could you please provide instructions for generating allure xml reports after running the tests, but without running a build?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Generally speaking you should [AllureTestListener](https://github.com/allure-framework/allure-core/blob/master/allure-testng-adaptor/src/main/java/ru/yandex/qatools/allure/testng/AllureTestListener.java) to your tests classpath so TestNG can automatically use this listener. This is done by adding the following dependency to **ivy.xml**:

```
<dependency org="ru.yandex.qatools.allure" name="allure-testng-adaptor" rev="1.4.11"/>
```

Then you need to run your tests in any way you want (e.g. by using your IDE runner). After running tests you should have a set of XML files generated by default in **target/allure-results**.

After getting these files just use a [command line report generator](https://github.com/allure-framework/allure-cli):

```
$ allure generate -v 1.4.11 target/allure-results
```

Comment: That's exactly what I want to do. But how the allure adapter knows about "target/allure-results" path if there is no build.xml file? I've added the dependency, but xml reports are still not generated.

Comment: Check that your classpath contains allure-testng.jar file.

Comment: It doesn't, but I didn't download allure-testng.jar, I only added ru.yandex.qatools.allure dependecy to my Ivy.xml. How can I download it?